# Is there a way of getting the index of an item in a random list in powershell

Tags: windows, list, powershell

I have a file in a powershell script containing data, say:

```
1
2
3
```

If I get a random item from that list, and I have the full list, how could I get the index of the item (3 = $List[2]; 1 = $List[0]? The list is not actual numbers, but that was an example. I am using Powershell 5.1 and have no urgent need for speed, as the list is small.

Comment: In short: Use `$array.IndexOf('foo')` for case-_sensitive_ string or non-string lookups, and `[Array]::FindIndex($array, [Predicate[string]] { 'foo' -eq $args[0] })` for case-_insensitive_ string lookups. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IndexOf`

> Searches for the specified object and returns the index of its first
> occurrence in a one-dimensional array or in a range of elements in the
> array.

```
$List = 1,2,3,4,5
$Random = $List | Get-Random
$Random 
5

$List.IndexOf($Random)
4
```

For further explanation check out this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/find-the-index-number-of-a-value-in-a-powershell-array/)

Comment: Nice, though it's worth mentioning that `.IndexOf()` is invariably case-_sensitive_, which may be unexpected / undesired.